# selenium ide having problems with dynamic id

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

i am testing our web based application using selenium. I am having problem in a button which has dynamic id and the class is similar to the last html page so i am unable to go ahead with the testing. below is the source of the button

**input id="aui_3_4_0_1_554" class="addto_cart_button" type="button" onclick="chkMaxRequestPerDay();" value="Request Quote">**

I want to know how can i tell selenium ide to check with value so that it can proceed

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can try using xpath with value,

```
//input[@value='Request Quote']
```

or

```
//input[@value='Request Quote' and @class='addto_cart_button']
```

Comment: thanks amit that doe work .. it able to find the button... But now the problem is when i add a command click infront of it it doesnt go through... but when i add a toggle point and then resume then its go through...

Answer (score 0):

I think something like below should also work

```
//input[contains(@id, 'aui_')]
```

or

```
//input[@class='addto_cart_button']
```

this will give you a List
loop through them and in the loop check

```
loop over List<Webelement> {
 if( webelement.getAttribute("onclick").indexOf("chkMaxRequestPerDay") != -1) {
     // here is the element. do what ever you want
 }
}
```